# Problemas con la versión de node.js

Tags: nodejs, anaconda

Tengo un problema con la versión de node, que creo que podría estar originado por la versión de node de anaconda, pero no estoy seguro, y tampoco sé cómo arreglarlo.

El caso es que tengo una máquina con ubuntu, en la que estoy tratando de actualizar mi versión de node, pero no me deja:

```
(base) roberto@roberto:~/Documentos/Proyectos/node/web$ nvm install v14.16.1
Downloading and installing node v14.16.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.1/node-v14.16.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100,0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v14.16.1 (npm v3.10.10)
```

Confirmo que tengo instalada la versión 14 y que es la quiero usar:

```
(base) roberto@roberto:~/Documentos/Proyectos/node/web$ nvm list
   v12.18.2
   v14.16.0
   v14.16.1
->       system
default -> v14.16.0
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v14.16.1) (default)
stable -> 14.16 (-> v14.16.1) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.16.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.1 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.16.1

(base) roberto@roberto:~/Documentos/Proyectos/node/web$ nvm use 14.16.1
Now using node v14.16.1 (npm v3.10.10)
```

También he probado a ponerla como por defecto:

```
(base) roberto@roberto:~/Documentos/Proyectos/node/web$ nvm alias default v14.16.1
default -> v14.16.1
```

Aquí, cuando trato de ver qué versión usa el sistema, me sigue apareciendo la v6, que creo que es la de anaconda. También he intentado forzarlo para que use mi versión 14, pero me da ese error que dice que no está en la cache de descargas.

```
(base) roberto@roberto:~/Documentos/Proyectos/node/web$ node -v
v6.13.1
(base) roberto@roberto:~/Documentos/Proyectos/node/web$ n use 14 app
 Error: '14' (14.16.1) not in downloads cache
```

¿Cómo podría arreglarlo, a ser posible sin cargarme la instalación de Anaconda?

Comment: Si tienes disponible `nvm` entonces intenta colocar la versión completa: `nvm use 14.16.1`. Adicionalmente podrías mostrar las versiones que tienes instaladas, esto con el comando `nvm list` para corroborar que la version 14.16.1 está instalada y disponible.

Comment: Sí, sí, aunque eso no cambia nada. El sistema sigue usando la versión cuando hago node -v

Comment: Tal vez algo de lo que hay en este [issue de GitHub](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1184) te pueda ayudar, parece ser un problema relacionado a nvm.

Comment: Gracias Ricardo, me ha servido para saber lo que sospechaba which node: ${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/node
Utiliza el node de anaconda, pero sigo sin saber como repararlo para que no use ese y utilice el que he instalado con nvm.